# Couchbase temporary failure

Tags: memcached, couchbase

I'm using couchbase 2.0.1 and using:

```
OperationFuture<Boolean> set = client.set(keySesionCanal, 0, sesionCanal, CouchdbClient.TRANSCODER_SESION_CANAL);
                            logger.info( set.getStatus().getMessage() );
```

Sometimes I get an error with message:  temporary failure

I'm pretty new using couchbase and I'm not sure what is happening.
In couchbase logs I can see a lot of messages as:
"Total memory use reached to the low water mark, stop warmup"

Could it be the cause?

Another weird log for me is:
" Sending TAP_OPAQUE with command "opaque_enable_auto_nack" and vbucket 0"
" TAP (Producer) eq_tapq:replication_ns_1@x.x.x.x - Suspend for 5.00 secs"

What is the meaning of this? Where I can find documentation about?

Comment: Seems is due a ramQuotaMB reached. http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#appendix-troubleshooting-views-technical-background (search for temporary failures). I will monitor logs, if all it's ok this is the answer!

Comment: ramQuotaMB was not reached and I get the same error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as you are hitting the limits of the amount of memory available for caching. The cluster will attempt to free up memory (by ejecting not-recently-used items from RAM) but if you are writing data too fast to the cluster for it to free up memory before it reaches the high watermark, you may see `TEMPFAIL` errors - which indicate the client should back off and retry. This is covered from the Server-side in [Ejection, eviction and working-set managerment](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#ejection-eviction-and-working-set-management).

Exactly how you handle this depends on the specific SDK you are using, but general information is available under [Handling temporary out-of-memory errors](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#handling-temporary-out-of-memory-errors) in the Developer Guide.

Note that the low/high watermark algorithm was improved in subsequent releases so you may have a better experience with the latest release (2.0.1 is quite old now).

Comment: Note that while the UI shows it that way, technically there is no `TEMP OOM`.  There is only TMPFAIL.  It can come up in other circumstances such as during bucket flush.